# How to log all Internet traffic that goes through a server running Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, logging

I have a need to find out how to log all Internet traffic of all users on a network that uses a Windows Server 2008 machine to provide Internet access to the entire network. I know, since this server provides Internet access to all machines on the network, that all Internet traffic is funneled through this machine.

What programs are available for logging all Internet traffic of all network users? Also, is there a feature built into Windows Server 2008 that allows this?

Comment: A little more detail:  What kind of info do you need?  Just websites visited?  Connections?  Every packet?

Comment: Also, just as a reminder:  make sure you have written permission from HR, etc...

Comment: Are you authorized to do this?

Comment: If only ServerFault recognized that I created this question on StackOverflow and IT moved it here. I CAN'T EDIT THE QUESTION!!

Comment: To clarify, The main focus is on Websites Visited, but other stuff would be a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably do this with [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29). I am running it as a web filter and cache on a Windows machine.

It's open source and very configurable.

http://www.squid-cache.org/

EDIT - not sure why I am down-voted here.  Running Squid as a proxy and pointing all other machines it would accomplish this.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but A> Only if "everything" is web based, and B> everything is preconfigured to use squid as the proxy.  I am guessing that this is not the solution set being looked for.

Comment: I'd say a. squid is nto a windows utility (netmon is) b. question is not how to add a proxy but how to simply monitor traffic.

Comment: Point taken..thanks for responding. Maybe I am just a big fan of Squid, but I think I would still recommend it. Its lite on resources and has been running on Windows for years. True that all machines would have to be configured to run through it.

Comment: I think SQUID is an excellent idea, though obviously we need to clarify whether the questioner wants all traffic or just web traffic. I too have used the Windows port of SQUID extensively and it's an excellent Windows web proxy, though admittedly configuring it can involve some head scratching. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

[Network Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Network_Monitor) [3.3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a feature built into Server 2008.  There is a product called Internet Access Monitor that appears to do what you want:

http://www.redline-software.com/eng/products/iam/

It is a commercial product however.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has an "Network Monitor" Windows component utility which can capture all network traffic. There are also [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) equivalents like WinDump.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture *all* (there may be some things it misses, but I am not aware of any) traffic you can always use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). However keep in mind this will be a **VERY** detailed trace unless you know what paticular filters you are after (for example, just HTTP traffic?) in which case there may be more specific applications.